# Why does that regex work?

Tags: php, regex

```
'@^(?<!h2.).*\s*\n@'
```

and this

```
'@^(?<!h2.).*\n@'
```

do not on the following file

```
la-la-la

h2. ohoho

abc
def
```

which is read by file_get_contents() in a string

Actually, the regex is called within the following expression

```
TextileThis(preg_replace('@^(?<!h2.).*\s*\n@','',file_get_contents($that_file)));
```

So I just wanted the first string of the file to be gone if it does not match `^h2\..*\s*$` but since I cannot say «do not match that regex» in php I had to use this ‘lookbehind’ form.

I should mention that the both of the regex form work, but the first form works well and with the second form I get the line with `h2.` unprocessed by textile and leaved as is. Textile requires `h2.` string to be separated from the below text by one interval, and that’s all, so I just can’t get why is it leaved unparsed and how those regex expressions actually affect the line.

I also checked my source files and there are no trailing spaces.

Comment: sorry misread your question from my previous answer.  You mentioned `both of the regex form work`, so what's not working again?

Comment: Er… What am I disappointed in the output? The both form can delete what I want get rid of, but the shorter form seems to be deleting something more(?) and the longer form finds for itself a whitespace somewhere (but from where?). Nevertheless the longer form seems to be giving the output as I want, but I cannot be sure that the result always will be correct until I understand what exactly do they match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get your problem, but I try to explain you the difference between those regexes

1. `@^(?<!h2.).*\s*\n@`

   and this
2. `@^(?<!h2.).*\n@`

`\s` is a whitespace character, that means it includes also newline characters like `\r` and `\n`.

So **1.** will remove also the second empty row, because `\s` matches the newline at the end of the first row and your explicit `\n` will match at the end of the second row.

Your second expression will only remove the first row, because the `\n` will match already at the end of the first row and the regex will leave the second empty row unmatched.

So I assume your problem with the second regex results from the empty row the resulting string starts with.

Comment: I was thinking about \s but idea that it can match not only whitespace characters looked stupid to me. And it still does. Could you provide a link where it’s written black on white that \s matches newline character please?
Also is there something I can match spaces and tabs with, but not newlines and caret return, [:white:] by POSIX or something?

Comment: Okay, I finally get it. It does exactly as you wrote, now I am sure. Before that I was looking at the code through Firebug and it has formatted HTML, but when I sought at sources I found that if second line of the file is present, Textile will start a new paragraph `<p>` from it, and do not process `h2. ` included in it as a header.

Comment: @user685107, A good resource for regex in general is [regular-expressions.info here character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)